# Issues getting started with google sheets API

Tags: python, json, google-sheets, pygsheets

I am trying to use python `gsheets` library to download a google sheets document as a `csv` file using the following tutorial: (https://pypi.org/project/gsheets/)

I have done all of the following:

- `pip install gsheets`
- Logged into Google Developer Console and created New credentials > OAuth client ID
- Downloaded the `json` file of the client ID I created and saved it into my users folder as: `client_secrets.json`

According to the example project I'm following another file, named storage.json in this example, will be created after successful authorization to cache OAuth data.

I then try creating a Sheets object:

```
>>> from gsheets import Sheets

>>> sheets = Sheets.from_files('~/client_secrets.json', '~/storage.json')
```

But when I do this I get the following error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/client_secrets.json'`

I know that the `client_secrets.json`  is in my user directory and properly spelled, why else would I be getting this error?

Comment: 'C:/Users/client_secrets.json' is not your user directory, right? It is probably something like 'C:/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/client_secrets.json'. I recommend you use os.path instead of hardcoded paths like  '~/...'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are using windows, meaning the Users is not your actual directory, it is actually `C:/Users/username/`

You could have Documents and Desktop and Downloads folders in there.

Try this instead of using the tilde.

```
from gsheets import Sheets

sheets = Sheets.from_files(r'C:\Users\username\client_secrets.json', r'C:\Users\username\storage.json')
```

Comment: I have tried that as well, I just get the same error that the file is not found even though it is in the directory

Comment: @NicLovin check out the code i just updated, note the direction of the slashes and the r before the strings

Comment: it's working now, I think the issue was a mixture of saving in the correct directory as you said, and I accidentally named my file ```client_secrets.json``` when it was already saved as a ```.json``` file so I think the reason it wasn't being found was because it was saved as ```client_secrets.json.json```. Now i have a new error: ```oauth2client.clientsecrets.InvalidClientSecretsError: Missing property "redirect_uris" in a client type of "web".```